# tsv file upload using control file not detect empty columns

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader, csv

I have a control file similar to bellow.

```
load data 
infile 'input.tsv'
badfile 'inputbad.bad'
discardfile 'inputdiscard.dsc'
truncate
into table SIM_RCNC_TO_POSTALCODE
fields terminated by '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           ( col1 CHAR(4000),
             col2 CHAR(4000),
             col3 CHAR(4000),
             col4 CHAR(4000),
             col5 CHAR(4000)
           )
```

bellow is the input.tsv content

```
670535  535 text 1      7244
670536  536 text 1  text 2  7244
```

It contains 2 tab characters between "text 1" and 7244 in first line. But it will insert to table as bellow.

```
col1    col2  col3     clo4     col5
670535  535   text 1   7244
670536  536   text 1   text 2   7244
```

Row number 1 is incorrect and row number 2 is correct. Could someone explain me the issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line: (OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"').  It seems to be incompatible with the "fields terminated by '\t'" line when the character is a TAB.

Just stumbled on some info: http://technologydribble.info/2008/11/12/sqlloader-and-tab-delimited-input-data/